# What is this plant? (Possibly a weed)

Tags: identification

A couple of months ago I repotted a small succulent, and this little thing shot up beside it. I repotted it to see what would become of it and this is how it looks currently. (I should have included something for scale, but the pot is 10cm diameter.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm sure it's just a weed of some sort that got mixed in with the soil I used, but I can't match it to anything in the garden. I was hoping someone here could identify it and would appreciate any help in doing so!

Comment: Can it be tomato?

Comment: Yep, definitely looks like a tomato seedling. Tomato seeds are tough little things and are often found growing at sewage works after passing through the human gut.

Comment: Agree with tomato. But it could also be a nightshade. In the past I've had a mystery plant that look a bit like a tomato, and when it flowered, realised / was able to identify it as nightshade. (and out it came!)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions folks; more interesting than I thought! I'll keeping looking after it and see what happens.

Comment: If your sense of smell is good, brush the leaf and smell. @benn , change comment to answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could very well be a tomato, or like others suggest in the comments, another member of the [Solanacae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanaceae) (nightshade) family.

Here an example of how young tomato [plant](https://www.colourbox.com/image/young-tomato-plants-image-4154906) looks like, very similar leaves. You can wait for the flowers and fruit, they can give more information.